# how to use git as cloud storage to work from two different machine?

Tags: git, github

I'm not sure what question I should ask so I'll try explaining my circumstance.

I want to work with 2 different machine, one at home and one at work. In my mind I planned to use git as kind of online storage so when I want to code at home I can just `git pull` then `git push` to save the changes and do the same for machine at work.

I just recently realized how important a good commit history are. previously I just commit with "save for today" message. after browsing around I found a kind of solution, that is using `git commit --amend` to make a coherent commit history and use `git push -f` to force pushing. now I always get warning 'merge failed' whenever I try to git pull. tried `git clean -df` and `git reset --hard` but it doesn't always work and for a quick fix I ended up re-cloning the entire project.

is there a better way to do things?

edit: I found a solution. what I want to do apparently is called synchronizing with remote while discarding local changes. it could be done with `git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/master && git clean -f -d`

Comment: "get warning 'merge failed' whenever I try to git pull" Please show the conversation as part of the question. You said what to Git, and Git said what to you?

Answer (score 0):

The commit history is definitely important and you should write small messages about what you have done (15 seconds more while doing the commit, could be saved hours in the future).

You could take a look in the information about --amend, it's common to say that you should not use this command in shared or public projects becuase it could be confusing and generate a lot of conflicts.

The best solution is just to do the commit with the message and the respective pushes and pulls. But, alternatively one basic solution could be having 2 branches: home and work. You should do merge between branches, pulls and pushes to have your repo up to date. In case you still get warnings you could use `git merge -X theirs branchxx` to avoid those conflicts. It just accept all the incoming changes where are conflicts. I think even if you have to do the commit, push and pull it's a good idea to have a different branch for home and work, so you can see a real history of what you have done in each place.